# SQL error: disk I/O error

Tags: sql, sqlite, embedded, posix

При записи в Sqlite вылетает лог с ошибкой `SQL error: disk I/O error`.
ОС стоит на mini-sd, все рабочее. Пробовал разные режимы работы бд, все ровно результат тот же. Прошу помощи т.к. информации очень мало.

Comment: `ОС стоит на mini-cd` - так видимо и файловая система readonly? Чему удивляться в отказе sqlite что-то писать?

Comment: @Мелкий, файл бд создается, но вот сама запись в него нет (создание таблиц и записей).